# C++: When inputing multiple values with one cin statement, is there a way to check whether each value failed individually?

Tags: c++

I need to input 2 variables on the same line, then check each variable individually to see if it failed, so that I can output a message saying specifically which variable was wrong.

I tried this:

```
int x;
int y;
cin >> x >> y;

if (cin.fail()) {
    cout << "wrong x type\n";
}
if (cin.fail()) {
    cout << "wrong y type\n";
}
else {
    cout << "right types\n";
}
```

I thought cin.fail() would only check one variable at a time, but that didn't work, so I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 4):

You can check the result of each `>>` individually, eg:

```
int x;
int y;

if (!(cin >> x)) {
    cout << "wrong x type\n";
}
else if (!(cin >> y)) {
    cout << "wrong y type\n";
}
else {
    cout << "right types\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading both `x` and `y` in at once, how about try reading them one at a time and checking the failure flag each time?

`cin.fail()` can only provide a single boolean result, and it does not have side effects (meaning calling it twice in a row will always provide the same result.) Therefore, there is no way to know which operation failed (or both) if you read in `x` and `y` at the same time.

Comment: I'd like to split it up, but this is for a school assignment, and I think I'm required to  read them in together.
EDIT: well I just checked and it turns out I actually am allowed to split them up, I guess I should have checked that first. Thanks for the help!

Comment: As I explain in the second paragraph, there is no way to differentiate if the first read failed or the second read failed if you do them together. Consider rereading the guidelines of your assignment. If the assignment wants you check if either failed, then you only have to test once. @emar5